# Remove app on App Store created by previous developer for our company

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

My company developed an app a few years back (last updated in 2016) for our news website. Our developer at the time uploaded it under their name. Since then though we have stopped working with them and have developed a new app that is under our name.

I have tried on a number of occasions to contact the app's owner to delete our old app via email, Facebook, Messenger etc but they just will not reply.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Send a real letter in a friendly tone to ask them to delist the app.

If that doesn't work, contact a lawyer and get them to send a letter.

If that doesn't work, discuss legal possibilities with the lawyer. This could include letting the developer know that the rights for the app's are yours and thus they have no right to distribute it on the app store (but only if that is really so), and it could include warning the developer that he's infringing on your trade marks or company name (if he is really doing so).